# Ruby sort_by for arrays returned by MySQL, date formatted as string

Tags: mysql, ruby, sorting, date

I have a database that has a `task` table.  In that table, there is a `date` column.  Those dates are formatted as strings, they aren't `Date`.

I'm trying to sort these tasks by date.  I already have an array of the tasks named `tasks`. I'm trying to replace it with the sorted array called `tasksByDate` using the below code.

```
tasksByDate = tasks.sort_by do |task|
  task[:date].to_date
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

I also tried without `to_date` just to see if it would sort it without it being  a date, and just being a string.

The `date` field is formatted as a string like so `2016-08-29`.  I used the `to_date` method on it somewhere else in the code, and it works great, so I didn't really think that was the problem.

---

**Edit 1**

I have checked that tasks actually contains a date, and it is formatted like explained.

The output of `p task.class` is `Array`

**Edit 2**

The output of `p task` is

```
[#<User id: 10, login: "my.name", hashed_password: "", date: "2016-08-29">]
```

Comment: Are you sure that the :date key exists within enumerator? Also, you might want to change the inner 'tasks' variable name to 'task' in order to avoid possible confusion. Try putting 'p tasks' inside the block and check what value it prints.

Comment: can you do something like to see output:

 tasks.map { |task| task }

Comment: @Pawel Duda I'll change the inner tasks to task, and printing the tasks prints them correctly, including the date key.

Comment: If you inspect 'task' variable inside the block by doing 'task.class', does it return Hash or something else? Edit: also try accessing it by task['date'] (with a string as a key instead) and see if the result is the same

Comment: @Pawel Duda Peculiar, when I try ```p task.class``` inside the block, it outputs ```Array```.  And when I try using 'date' as a string, I get the same error.

Comment: That seems to be the source of the problem. foo[:date] will not work if foo is an Array, since you cannot access its elements by a named key. My guess is that the nesting is one level deeper than you expect. Could you paste what does `p task` output?

Comment: @Pawel Duda I put the output under Edit 2.  I typed it in by hand, so I apologize for any errors, but I don't think there are any.  It actually output way more than that, but I tried to include only a small sample.

Comment: Note that you do not need to convert to date if you want to sort (thats the nice thing about the date format you have there), given everyday data. The real problem here had nothing to do with (in your case unnecessary) date sorting. Will try to find a better question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements appear to be nested deeper than you expected them to be. Change the your code to:

```
# use '{ }' instead of 'do end' for a single-line blocks
tasksByDate = tasks.sort_by { |task| task.first[:date].to_date }
```

Explanation:

What you see as an output of `p task`:

```
[#<User id: 10, login: "my.name", hashed_password: "", date: "2016-08-29">]
```

It means that this is an Array of elements. Notice the enclosing braces `[ ]`. So what you have to do in this case is `task.first`, which will return:

```
 #<User id: 10, login: "my.name", hashed_password: "", date: "2016-08-29">
```

From there you should be able to access the element's values by a key, like you intended:

```
task.first[:date]
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  Can you explain why ```.first``` takes it into the next layer?  I assumed that would just return the "first" element of the array?

Comment: @trueCamelType I have added an explanation, let me know if that suffices :)

Comment: Forgot to mention, for your answer, the ```to_date``` can be removed as it causes another error.  Also worth mentioning for anyone else who finds this, while this gets rid of my error (which is why the question exists), the array still isn't getting sorted.  That's a problem for another question though.