# Why isn't my sort_array sorting?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array named `tasks` with the contents shown below.

```
[[#<Task id: 1, date: "2016-08-23", members: 5>, #<Task id: 2, date: "2016-08-20", members: 4> #<Task id: 3, date: "2016-08-24", members: 6>]]
```

Currently, when I print these, it prints correctly, in the format shown above.

My goal is to sort the array by the date.

```
sortedTasks = tasks.sort_by do |task|
  task.first[:date]
end

p sortedTasks
```

Unfortunately, this prints the exact same array, with no changes.

I thought maybe there was a problem with date, and tried using `to_date` but that wasn't the issue.

To test, I decided just to use a regular integer, so I used the below

```
sortedTasks = tasks.sort_by do |task|
  task.first[:members]
end

p sortedTasks
```

Same thing, no changes.

The confusing part is that there are no error messages, it just prints `sortedTasks` as if it were the original `tasks` Array with no changes.

`p task.class` confirms that it's an Array.

Comment: What do you think the `.first` in your block is doing? Why is it necessary to have it there?

Comment: The ```.first``` fixed a problem that may have actually not been the problem for a question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213643/ruby-sort-by-for-arrays-returned-by-mysql-date-formatted-as-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your pasted array is correct, you are sorting an array containing one element, which is another array. As it is only one element, it is already in order.

I expect you mean something along the lines of

```
sortedTasks[0].sort_by do |task|
  task[:date]
end
```

Comment: And in case you have multiple arrays within the first array, try doing `tasks.flatten.sort_by (...)`

Comment: If I sort in place like this, don't I need a ! at the end of sort_by?